# Why would my microwave continually rotate when connected to a voltage stabilizer which is also used for a refrigerator?

Tags: electrical, refrigerator, electric-motor, microwave-oven

When I connected my microwave oven to a voltage stabilizer which is being used for refrigerator,the microwave oven motor starts working without any functions provided.The motor keeps on rotating at lower rpm. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Perhaps your "voltage stabilizer" doesn't output sinusoidal voltage and this produces harmonics which upset the oven's sensors.

Comment: Does the microwave really need to be connected to the stabilizer?  I can understand why a refrigerator would need it, but not a microwave.

Comment: I agree with redgritybrick+.  A micro wave has sensitive electronics by its basic design, many refrigerators are very simple motor driven compressors with some lights and fans I would say the microwave would benefit more than a fridge, in fact a fridge creates surges and dips when the motor starts & stops.

Comment: I think the obvious but un-answers question is, have you tested the microwave without the stabiliser since you noticed the problem?

Comment: So just the turntable is going?

Answer (score 0):

You should / MUST not connect stabilizer made for refrigerator to microwave oven.
Stabilizer for fridge will be of capacity around 0.5kw and that for microwave oven should be around 2kw or more.

Comment: It depends on the size of the stabilizer without that information you really can't say you must not.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, it could be due to **surges** at the gate firing the Microwave triac that controls the power to the rotation motor. These firing could be caused by non-sinusoidal voltages coming from the stabilizer.

A power overload is unlikely since  the motor needs less then 100W. And the powerfull magnetron should not run. Is it a combination MW with grill and hot air?

Normally the door switches will completely switch off a MW, at least the magnetron. As suggested by other posters, a simple comparison at a normal outlet with doors opened/closed could help to find the problem.